# How to size svg according to various devices?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, svg, responsive-design

I am using SVG for an illustration I have created the following view
for all desktop size [image]

but when I change to view to a large screen or small it change its position Example
[image]

code HTML

```
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <div class="svg-container">
    <img src="./assets/Asset 1.svg" alt="" class="background">
    <img src="./assets/Asset 3.svg" alt="" class="magnifier">
    <img src="./assets/Asset 31.svg" alt="" class="pc-table">
    <img src="./assets/Asset 28.svg" alt="" class="monitor">
    <img src="./assets/Asset 32.svg" alt="" class="keyboard">
    <img src="./assets/Asset 27.svg" alt="" class="designer">
    <img src="./assets/Asset 26.svg" alt="" class = "client">
  </div>
</body>


@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
img{
    position: relative;
}
.background {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    bottom:5rem;
    width: 47rem;
}
.magnifier {
    position: relative;
    float: bottom;
    top:335px;
    left:535px;
    width: 12rem;
    transform: rotate(5deg);
}
.pc-table {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    top: 10rem;
    left: 40rem;
    width: 21rem;
}
.monitor {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    width: 10rem;
    left: 57rem;
    bottom: 8rem;
    // top: 2rem;
}
.keyboard {
    width: 10rem;
    float: right;
    left: 33.5rem;
    bottom:11.5rem;
}
.designer {
    width: 3rem;
    float: right;
    left: 33rem;
    bottom:14.4rem;
}
.client {
    width: 10rem;
    float: right;
    left: 35rem;
    bottom:10rem;
}
```

I have used the image for the SVG link and style them according to in the CSS and used perfectly align them accordingly that need in my  style but it changing it devises size it shows the following image

Comment: can you provide link

Comment: @ArindamSarkar what link you want i will try to provide you

Comment: where this code actually runs

Comment: actually,  i am running on my local machine using angular

Comment: @ArindamSarkar i can help you to provide more detail

Comment: you write a media query for different device. || Or you can marge total Image in Adobe illustrator.

Comment: @ArindamSarkar I first design in illustrator and export into an svg file and then position according to my design  but all the illustration you see is exported differently and position them individually using HTML and CSS and I am using bootstrap

Comment: I mean Instead of 3 SVG you should use 1 SVG. I mean you should make one single SVG.

Comment: @ArindamSarkar oh I got your point but i need to animate each SVG  using gsap

Comment: oh. Then you need to help of @media query

Comment: @ArindamSarkar so it can be done on bootstrap instead of media query?

Comment: no, I think you need to write custom CSS .

Comment: @ArindamSarkar so I  have to use media query anyhow

Comment: so I have to create separately view on illustrator then I code them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's so difficult to control all those SVG with relative positions. I recommend you to unify them in just one with Adobe Illustrator.

If you can, use the SVG as a background image

```
.svg-container{
    background-image: url('YOUR_PATH/YOUR_IMAGE.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: but what to do for responsive

Comment: You can animate the SVG content (g or paths), or even give them classes. As I said, you don't need to have all of those. You can still work with its content once it's unified. Besides, with `background-size: cover;` background will automatically resize to the 100% width of the viewport.

Comment: so need to use media query